# iOS - creating a new directory in Documents folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. What I want is to create a new directory called Audio if one doesn't already exists, and then save the file into the Audio directory. The current output is that a directory is not created and the file is saved to the Documents directory. Here is the code I'm using:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *audioDirPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Audio", [appDelegate applicationDocumentsDirectory].absoluteString];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:audioDirPath]) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:audioDirPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
}
NSURL *audioDirURL = [NSURL URLWithString:audioDirPath];
NSURL *path = [NSURL URLWithString:@"test.mp3" relativeToURL:audioDirURL];
[self.documentData writeToURL:path atomically:YES];
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are not forming the path correctly. And anyway it is better to use URLs wherever you can. When you do, use `URLByAppendingPathComponent:` to "drill down" a level. Thus:

```
NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager new];
NSError* err = nil;
NSURL* docsurl =
    [fm URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
               inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil
                 create:YES error:&err];
// error checking omitted
NSURL* myfolder = [docsurl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Audio"];
BOOL ok =
    [fm createDirectoryAtURL:myfolder
        withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&err];
// error-checking omitted
```

And now `myfolder` is the URL of the folder you want to write into. Again, use `URLByAppendingPathComponent` to derive the URL for the file you want to write to.

Comment: And see my book for further examples: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_basic_file_operations